# Automatically allowing sites to use my camera

Tags: flash, camera, flash-player, adobe-flash

How to allow automatically when a site requests to use my camera?

I dont want the settings manager popup dialog to appear, but I want the **`allow`** permission to be granted always.

Is there a way to do it via scripts?

Comment: this should pose a severe security risk. Any webpage or trojan may record you on the background without noticing you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this per site.

1. Open the [Flash Player Settings Manager](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html).
2. Open the website privacy settings.
3. Find the site in question and then click the Always allow.

Restart the browser.